# How to use nested WillPopScope in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, navigation

In my app I have a WillPopScope widget wrapping the root Scaffold to prevent users from accidentally exiting the app. Also I have an app bar inside the Scaffold with a search button which when clicked will show a search input in the app bar(similar to whatsapp search). When search is toggled I want the back button press to exit search so I have wrapped my search input with another WillPopScope expecting that the inner most WillPopScope will take control and exit search but what happens is when there are multiple WillPopScope widgets nested, control is always given to outer most one of them. Is there any possible way to make the control go to inner most WillPopScope.

Answer (score 0):

You could use **leading: IconButton(...)** in your AppBar search bar.

This overrides the backbutton and so you will not need an inner WillPopScope.

Comment: I already have a leading button to exit search but I also want to have the same functionality with back button press. I believe that would be a better user experience than just having back button in AppBar.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BackButtonListener(
      onBackButtonPressed: () {
        /// todo: close search widget
        return Future.value(true);
      },
      child: SearchBar(),
    );
  }
```